# Hibernate Session Does not released in logout operation

Tags: hibernate, session

there is a project on hibernate and struts when I login in the project hibernate session are created and when I click on logout link sessions remains same.

I am using `show processlist;` command in putty to see the session details.

what could be the reason behind this situation?